# Slow Query Execution

Tags: oracle

I have the following query which is taking time to execute.I think it is due to Group By. Can anybody modify this query and execute query without using GroupBy but the output result should be same.

```
SELECT order_id,
       sum(item_total)item_total,
       sum(discount)discount,
       sum(shipping_amount)shipping_amount,
       sum(tax_total)tax_total,
       sum(grand_total)grand_total,
       order_status,
       order_date,
       store_label,
       promotion_key,
       store_identifier,
       ship_party_name,
       ship_address1,
       ship_address2,
       ship_city,
       ship_zip,
       ship_state,
       ship_to_phone,
       ship_type,
       bill_party_name,
       bill_address1,
       bill_address2,
       bill_city,
       bill_state,
       bill_zip,
       bill_to_phone,
       bill_to_email,
       card_brand,
       credit_card_number
FROM apps.SCHL_ORDER_DETAILS_V
WHERE UCN=?
  AND order_id=?
GROUP BY order_id,
         order_status,
         order_date,
         store_label,
         promotion_key,
         store_identifier,
         bill_party_name,
         bill_address1,
         bill_address2,
         bill_city,
         bill_state,
         bill_zip,
         bill_to_phone,
         bill_to_email,
         card_brand,
         credit_card_number,
         ship_party_name,
         ship_address1,
         ship_address2,
         ship_city,
         ship_zip,
         ship_state,
         ship_to_phone,
         ship_type,
         store_label
```

Comment: if u need aggregation then u cannot avoid it i think... first of all we need explain plan, and tables row counts, DDL, (maybe for the apps.SCHL_ORDER_DETAILS_V table, or view )

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it helps - but you can try put your filter into subquery

```
select 
order_id,
       sum(item_total)item_total,
       sum(discount)discount,
       sum(shipping_amount)shipping_amount,
       sum(tax_total)tax_total,
       sum(grand_total)grand_total,
       order_status,
       order_date,
       store_label,
       promotion_key,
       store_identifier,
       ship_party_name,
       ship_address1,
       ship_address2,
       ship_city,
       ship_zip,
       ship_state,
       ship_to_phone,
       ship_type,
       bill_party_name,
       bill_address1,
       bill_address2,
       bill_city,
       bill_state,
       bill_zip,
       bill_to_phone,
       bill_to_email,
       card_brand,
       credit_card_number
from (
SELECT order_id,
       item_total,
       discount,
       shipping_amount,
       tax_total,
       grand_total,
       order_status,
       order_date,
       store_label,
       promotion_key,
       store_identifier,
       ship_party_name,
       ship_address1,
       ship_address2,
       ship_city,
       ship_zip,
       ship_state,
       ship_to_phone,
       ship_type,
       bill_party_name,
       bill_address1,
       bill_address2,
       bill_city,
       bill_state,
       bill_zip,
       bill_to_phone,
       bill_to_email,
       card_brand,
       credit_card_number
    FROM apps.SCHL_ORDER_DETAILS_V
    WHERE UCN=?
      AND order_id=?
   )
    GROUP BY order_id,
             order_status,
             order_date,
             store_label,
             promotion_key,
             store_identifier,
             bill_party_name,
             bill_address1,
             bill_address2,
             bill_city,
             bill_state,
             bill_zip,
             bill_to_phone,
             bill_to_email,
             card_brand,
             credit_card_number,
             ship_party_name,
             ship_address1,
             ship_address2,
             ship_city,
             ship_zip,
             ship_state,
             ship_to_phone,
             ship_type,
             store_label
```